# Multiple lines on the same line graph using ggplot2 showing up flat

Tags: r, ggplot2, linegraph

I am new to ggplot2 and am trying to create a line graph which displays change over time for 4 countries on a single graph. Below is a simplified version of my data format (I wanted to include it in the post just in case my issue had something to do with the layout).

[image: Data Format]

I have tried the following to create a multi-line plot, but it returns a graph with flat lines for each country (it doesn't seem to be referencing the data for each column even though they are all numeric in class).

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=date)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = 'Country A'), color = 'peachpuff4') +
  geom_line(aes(y = 'Country B'), color = 'salmon3') +
  geom_line(aes(y = 'Country C'), color = 'lavenderblush4') +
  geom_line(aes(y = 'Country D'), color = 'darkred')
```

Any advice re data format or overall approach appreciated :-)

Comment: Try to use backticks instead of single quotes for the country columns. The `aes()` function thinks of strings as the string itself instead of column names. It might also be easier to convert your data to a long format.

Comment: @teunbrand : that worked like a charm, thank you so much for your help!!